# not printing to textbox

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I am trying to create a way of retrieving from a hashtable an authorID for the articleName that the user enters. Here is the code that is activated on the client's side when the user presses a button:

```
public String getAuthorID() // returns a String
    {
             try
        {
            articleName = txtArticleName.getText();
            argAuthorID = new Vector();// create vector for the args
            argAuthorID.addElement(articleName);// name to search for to get AuthorID

            // make the call to the server
            authorIDVector = (Integer)client.execute("GetSize.sendAuthorID", argAuthorID);
            System.out.println(argAuthorID);
          }
            catch (XmlRpcException exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" +
            Integer.toString(exception.code) + ": " +
                               exception.getCause() + "" + exception.toString());
          } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" + exception.toString());
          }
        String StrAuthorID = Integer.toString(authorID); // Cast AuthorID to String
        return StrAuthorID;
    }
```

This is the method on the server side:

```
public int sendAuthorID(String articleNameRequest) {
        // get info from the hashtable
        aNumber = (Integer) theHashtable.getAuthorID(articleNameRequest); // was this.
        return aNumber;
    }
```

This is the code in the class that contains the hashtable:

```
public int getAuthorID(String articleName)
{
    int intfoundit;
    String foundit =  (String)hashtab.get(articleName);
    System.out.print(foundit);
    intfoundit = Integer.parseInt(foundit);
    System.out.print(foundit);
    System.out.print(intfoundit);
    return intfoundit;
}
```

The program can retrieve the AuthorID but won't input it into the textbox. Via testing I discovered that the exception was thrown by this code:

```
catch (XmlRpcException exception) {
            System.err.println("JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #" +
            Integer.toString(exception.code) + ": " +
                               exception.getCause() + "" + exception.toString());
```

This is the error that is given:

> 'JavaClient: XML-RPC Consumer Fault #0:
>   nullorg.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 3377"'

UPDATE: removed the space before the ID number in the hashtable and it doesn't throw an error anymore but it still isn't inputting the ID number into the textbox instead it just inputs a '0'

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be failing in cases when you have spaces in your string. As we can see in your exception trace that `parseInt` failed to parse `" 3377"`  and it threw `NumberFormatException` while executing:

```
intfoundit = Integer.parseInt(foundit);
```

So you may try to `trim` the string and see whether it solves your problem:

```
intfoundit = Integer.parseInt(foundit.trim());
```

Better you should do the trim where you are saving/putting the key/value in the hashtable.

Comment: I just did that and it fixed the problem but the method doesn't seem to be actually returning the ID number for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first problem was space before ID number on the hashtable because the space couldn't be converted to an Integer.

The answer to the second problem was that the following line was trying to convert the wrong variable

```
    String StrAuthorID = Integer.toString(authorID); // Cast AuthorID to String
```

because the Integer was in the `AuthorID` variable

I corrected this by changing

```
        authorIDVector = (Integer)client.execute("GetSize.sendAuthorID", argAuthorID);
```

to

```
        authorID = (Integer)client.execute("GetSize.sendAuthorID", argAuthorID);
```